# Is there a way to have an app notification to be persistent in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

We have a requirement to create a notification that stays on screen for the period of the event. Every time user clicks on it, it should navigate to the app, but notification remains on the lock screen/notification screen.

Is it possible in iOS?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` and re-scheduling every time the user opens or dismisses the local notification? So it should reappear on the lock screen.

Comment: Sounds like a good workaround @RainerSchwarz :) Is there a provision in the current SDK to keep the same notification active for a duration?

Comment: Before rescheduling the notification, check if your event is still running. A simple comparison of the current timestamp with the timestamp of the end of your event should do the trick: if current timestamp is prior to the end timestamp, show the notification again, otherwise not.